# HTML - How do I interacting with each individual image when they are overlaid on each other?

Tags: html, css, image, photoshop, imagemap

I built a map in Photoshop where each layer is a piece of the map. When they come together they make the whole map.

[image: Photoshop]

What I want to do, is have an interactive map on my website where each piece of the map is a button. However, when I export them as PNG's (with transparent background) and overlay them in HTML I can only interact with the top most image. Does anyone have a suggestion for another way I can do this?

Here is my HTML...

```
<body style="background: rgba(0,0,0,1.00)">
    
<div class="parent">    
<img class="image1" src="images/Guadrants/Guadrant_1.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Guadrant_2.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_3.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_4.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_5.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_6.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_7.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_8.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_9.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_10.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_11.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_12.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_13.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_14.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_15.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_16.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_17.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_18.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_19.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_20.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_21.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_22.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_23.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_24.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_25.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_26.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_27.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_28.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_29.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_30.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_31.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_32.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_33.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_34.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_35.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_36.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_37.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_38.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_39.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_40.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_41.png">
<img class="image2" src="images/Guadrants/Quadrant_42.png">
</div>  

</body>
```

Here is my CSS...

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.image1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 75%;
}
.image2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 75%;
 
}

.image2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
.image1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would use the images as SVG file format and not png file format the SVG:s gives you more possibilities in what you want to achieve.

From what I understood you want alot of different images to form one big image, then I would change the sizing and positioning in the HTML of each image so that it aligns as you want it and does not cover each other in order to form the bigger image.

Comment: Then you will have a bunch of smaller image pieces that you can play around with in order to form your big image